# code igniter 4, csrf problem after echo view and exit

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

my main purpose to include some pagedata on BaseController, To do so, i decided to put a protected function under basecontroller and i used it to display pages ( instead of return view('page') );

example of my code,

Under BaseController

```
protected function display($page = NULL,$data = NULL){
  global $settings;

  $general_data = array(
    'activeGoogleAnalytics' => $settings['activeGoogleAnalytics']
  );

  $data = array_merge($data,$general_data);

  echo view($page,$data);
  exit; // if exit is removed, csrf error is not appear, else there is csrf error while submitting forms
}
```

Then, i use display function as follows in my controllers,

```
public function index()
{
  //get some data
  $this->display('login/index',array(
   'someData' => '$someData',
  ));
}
```

This is actually working fine, i am merging two different arrays, and some content which are same in all pages are assigned to data array from BaseController.

My problem is whenever i submit form, i get csrf error "You cannot Perform this action". Even if i remove csrf protection from forms i got this error.

I found solution to the problem, by removing exit; from display function. But i am not sure what causes this problem or it is right decision. Because codeigniter is a framework, there should be better way of assigning page data ( which is same in all pages like website settings ).

Without using exit after echo, probably i ll face with AJAX problems in the future. Hence, i want to keep exit, or i want to learn easy way of assigning some data to view 's array from BaseController for all pages.

Comment: On your display function - `return` the view (removing echo and exit) and on the index() `return` the results of displayPage. In CI4 you need to return the View objects which get handled by the Response code.

Comment: if you mean using 2 times return, 1 in display function and 1 in index function it does not work, results in empty page. If you mean, get data from display function in index by simply adding $this->display, and returning data to index, then in index return view, it is not wanted property, i dont want to add $this->getdataFromBase() to all pages. My shared code is started to work with exit, it is fine for now, but abstract classes should be to add common content ( like website settings, name, config )  for all pages, now it is working fine but i dont know why exit sometimes causes problems.